# Swift control flow

Tags: ios, swift, controller, segue

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    submitTapped()
    if let scheduleController = segue.destination as? ScheduleController {
        scheduleController.jsonObject = self.info
    }
}
```

In submitTapped(), self.info is assigned a value. But when I run my app, self.info is reported as "nil". I tried setting breakpoints at each of the three lines, and it seems that submitTapped() doesn't execute until after this function is finished.

Why is this? Does it have to deal with threads? How can I get submitTapped() to execute before the rest? I'm just trying to move from one view controller to another while also sending self.info to the next view controller.

UPDATE:

I ended up figuring it out (for the most part) thanks to the answer below + my own testing.

```
@IBAction func submitTapped() {
    update() { success in
        if success {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showScheduler", sender: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // I'll probably check the segue identifier here once I have more "actions" implemented
    let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ScheduleController
    destinationVC.jsonObject = self.info
}

public func update(finished: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    ...
    self.info = jsonObject //get the data I need
    finished(true)
    ...
}
```

Comment: can you show what submitTapped does and where does it get its values?

Comment: submitTapped() creates a post request using a member variable string serialized into a JSON as the body that receives a JSON which is then saved into a member variable called info ([String : AnyObject]). I think the important part is that info is being set in this function, and that is the only part relevant to the segue. Do you need me to post the code itself?

Comment: @nuvaryan , you can `perform` segue when will you get value from `json` in a `closure`.  else use `completion` handler like as below answer

Comment: Thanks, I'll be sure to look into closures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The network request is an asynchronous task that occurs in the background and takes some time to complete. Your prepareForSegue method call will finish before the data comes back from the network.

You should look at using a completionHandler and also only triggering the segue once you have the data.

so your submitTapped function (probably best to rename this to update or something) will make the network request and then when it gets the data back will set the self.info property and then call performSegueWithIdentifier.

```
func update(completion: (Bool) -> Void) {
    // setup your network request. 
    // perform network request, then you'll likely parse some JSON

    // once you get the response and parsed the data call completion
    completion(true)
}

update() { success in
    // this will run when the network response is received and parsed.
    if success {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showSchedular")
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

Closures, Completion handlers an asynchronous tasks can be very difficult to understand at first. I would highly recommend looking at this [free course](https://www.udacity.com/course/ios-networking-with-swift--ud421) which is where I learnt how to do it in Swift but it takes some time.

This [video tutorial](https://teamtreehouse.com/library/closures-in-swift-2/closures-in-cocoa-touch/making-a-network-request) may teach you basics quicker.

Comment: No worries, I was just curios. I think someone hasn't read your comment above. I've come across this issue a number of times, especially when I was first learning swift and iOS. Give it a try and it should solve your issue. it would be quite helpful too if you could put the information about whats going on inside submitTapped into your question to help people understanding your issue properly

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very familiar with this syntax. Everything that happens (the network request and the segue) should only happen once a button is pressed. Should the button have an action or a segue (or both) and where would update be called?

Comment: I've provided some links which will help teach closures in swift and will solve this issue for you. I will also try to provide a more accurate example in the answer above when i can